# Total derivative of an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Today in Electromagnetism class appeared this doubt that the teacher couldn't explain, probably because is more a mathematical question.

Why does the total derivate outside the integral become a partial derivative inside it in the formula

$$\frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d t} \int E \ \Bbb d x = \int \frac {\partial E} {\partial t} \ \Bbb d x ?$$

$E$ is a function of $x$ and $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the left-hand side, the variable $x$ of $E$ is killed by the integration $\int \dots \Bbb d x$, so the only variable surviving integration is $t$, therefore $\int E \ \Bbb d x$ is a function of a single variable, $t$, hence the natural symbol to use is the one for functions of a single variable, i.e. $\frac {\Bbb d} {\Bbb d t}$.

In the right-hand side, once the derivative gets inside the integral, it sees a function of two variables ($t$ and $x$), therefore one should use the notation appropriate for functions of several variables, i.e. $\frac {\partial} {\partial t}$.